# Python: convert string array to int array in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame, duration is one of the attributes. The duration's content is like:

```
            array(['487', '346', ...,  '227', '17']).
```

And the df.info(), I get: Data columns (total 22 columns):

```
             duration        2999 non-null object
             campaign        2999 non-null object
             ...
```

Now I want to convert duration into int. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 4):

Use [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
df['duration'] = df['duration'].astype(int)
```

**Timings**

Using the following setup to produce a large sample dataset:

```
n = 10**5
data = list(map(str, np.random.randint(10**4, size=n)))
df = pd.DataFrame({'duration': data})
```

I get the following timings:

```
%timeit -n 100 df['duration'].astype(int)
100 loops, best of 3: 10.9 ms per loop

%timeit -n 100 df['duration'].apply(int)
100 loops, best of 3: 44.3 ms per loop

%timeit -n 100 df['duration'].apply(lambda x: int(x))
100 loops, best of 3: 60.1 ms per loop
```

Comment: nice timings, though I suggest tweaking it to use the same number of loops for easier comparison

Comment: Edited to have the same number of loops.

Answer (score 3):

```
df['duration'] = df['duration'].astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `int(str)`:

```
df['duration'] = df['duration'].apply(lambda x: int(x)) #df is your dataframe with attribute 'duration'
```

Comment: No need for the lambda, `.apply(int)` will work and give better performance.

Comment: In general, `lambda *args, **kwargs: f(*args, **kwargs)` is exactly equivalent to `f`